# I am trying to copy values from multiple workbooks into one worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a macro to copy multiple cells from one worksheet in one workbook to a master worksheet. I created a macro using the record tool however when I try to run it in a different workbook the first part of the code works for the different workbook, however the other parts refer back to the original sheet. I see that the macro keeps activating the specific window ("Vincent...") I was wondering how I can define the selected worksheet as a variable and thus perform the rest of the activates using that variable ?

```
Range("F4:F14").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Combined Spreadsheet.xlsx").Activate
Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=True
Windows("VincentCAIN107_Intra1_VD1_Rudd.xlsx").Activate
Range("H4:H14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Combined Spreadsheet.xlsx").Activate
Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=True
Windows("VincentCAIN107_Intra1_VD1_Rudd.xlsx").Activate
Range("N4:N14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Combined Spreadsheet.xlsx").Activate
Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=True
Windows("VincentCAIN107_Intra1_VD1_Rudd.xlsx").Activate
Range("R4:R14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Combined Spreadsheet.xlsx").Activate
Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=True
Windows("VincentCAIN107_Intra1_VD1_Rudd.xlsx").Activate
Range("S4:S14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Combined Spreadsheet.xlsx").Activate
Range("AP" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True _
    , Transpose:=True
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can clean up your code a bit. Here is an example:

```
Sub JoinArray()
    Dim master As Worksheet, source As Worksheet, copyCols() As Variant, pasteCols() As Variant, i As Integer

    Set master = Workbooks("Combined Spreadsheet").Worksheets(1)
    Set source = Workbooks("VincentCAIN107_Intra1_VD1_Rudd").Worksheets(1)
    copyCols = Array("F", "H", "N", "R", "S")
    pasteCols = Array("B", "L", "V", "AF", "AP")

    For i = 0 To UBound(copyCols)
        source.Range(copyCols(i) & "4:" & copyCols(i) & 14).Copy
        master.Range(pasteCols(i) & master.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Notes:

1. Set references to your worksheets upfront
2. If you know the columns you want to copy from and paste to you can define them in an array for reference

Comment: Great! this almost works. I was trying to do a define range approach recently but I wasn't sure how to use that paste function. I was wonder where I could implement the special paste option in this code?

Comment: Try keeping the `source.Range(copyCols(i) & "4:" & copyCols(i) & 14).Copy` line, delete the `Destination:=...` code and then add this as a new line below: `master.Range(pasteCols(i) & master.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True`

Comment: I get an synatx error subbing that code into the array

Comment: nvm I figure that out, any change to make this work on a bunch of workbooks in a folder?

Comment: sorry it did work, Another issue is that for one of the columns I only want to copy filled values, is it possible to implement this for the entire thing?

Comment: Not sure. Try googling `SpecialCells`.

Comment: ok, thanks for all your help, I tried changing the PAtespeical skipblanks to true but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your macro declare a string

```
DIM BookName As String
```

Then assign it the book name

```
BookName = "VincentCAIN107_Intra1_VD1_Rudd.xlsx"
```

Then you can use it with the `Windows` method

```
Windows(BookName).Activate
```

To simplify your code, add a function to handle the copying given the right parameters

```
Sub CopyCells(Book1 As String, Book2 As String, RngSrc As String, ColumnDest As String)
    Windows(Book1).Activate  
    Range(RngSrc).Select     
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(Book2).Activate
    Range(ColumnDest & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Using this function will reduce your source code to

```
Sub CopyWorkbooks()
    Dim Book1 As String
    Dim Book2 As String

    Book1 = "VincentCAIN107_Intra1_VD1_Rudd.xlsx"
    Book2 = "Combined Spreadsheet.xlsx"

    Call CopyCells(Book1, Book2, "F4:F14", "B")
    Call CopyCells(Book1, Book2, "H4:H14", "L")
    Call CopyCells(Book1, Book2, "N4:N14", "V")
    Call CopyCells(Book1, Book2, "R4:R14", "AF")
    Call CopyCells(Book1, Book2, "S4:S14", "AP")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I don't really understand how to implement this code, is sub copycells(book1..) a function that is subsequently used in the sub copycell()? therefore both have to placed in the window

Comment: It is just one function calling another.  I've renamed one of them to help with any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

For setting a variable as workbook : (example)

```
Option Explicit  'this forces to declare variables (, always good)

Sub MySub
Dim Wb as Workbook , MainWB as workbook

Set MainWB = Workbooks("Combined Spreadsheet.xlsx")    'assuming it is opened

Err.clear
On Error resume Next 'if the workbook is not opened yet, it will throw an error
Set Wb= Workbooks ("WhateverName.xls") ' <<<<<<<<<<  this is the way of setting the workbook to read from
If err<>0 then 'can also be written: if Wb is nothing then
    Err.clear
    Set Wb= Workbooks.Open (Thisworkbook.path & "\" & "WhateverName.xls") 'If Wb not open yet, we do it now, assuming the file is in the same path as this main workbook
end if

On Error Goto 0 'reset error handling

'work with Wb :
With Wb
    .Sheets("AnySheetYouWant").Range("AnyRange").Copy  'by the way, no need to select or activate, "selection" can be replaced by a range
    MainWB.range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
             SkipBlanks:=False , Transpose:=True
    .Save  ' just for example
    .Close ' just for example
End With

Set Wb = Nothing ' i like freeing memory at the end of Subs...
Set MainWB= Noting
End Sub
```

Macro Recorder is not too bad for starters , but soon it's really really bad programming...
Read stuff, use google, ask questions...